# Split invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take a line from a file `plainprogram.txt`, split it at the spaces, and store them in an array. This is the plain program text in `plainprogram.txt`:

```
5 cmt A program with a simple loop that counts down.
10 get x
20 if x = 0 goto 90
30 output x
40 let x = x – 1
50 goto 20
90 stop
```

It is supposed to resemble code from a terrible programming language. This is my code:

```
File.readlines("plainprogram.txt").each do |line|
  pieces = line.split()
end
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
3: from main.rb:13:in <main>
2: from main.rb:13:in each
1: from main.rb:14:in block in <main>
main.rb:14:in split: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
(ArgumentError)
```

I can't figure out why this code raises an error. I don't understand why `split` throws this error, nor how to fix it.

Comment: Can you show your `plainprogram.txt`? My guess is that you have some Unicode or other non-ASCII characters in there somehow.

Comment: I though Ruby defaulted to Unicode.

Comment: If you use a GNU-based environment (such as Linux or Cygwin), I want to see `hexdump -C plainprogram.txt | head`. It will show what funny characters might be in there.

Comment: no, its on windows

Comment: I don't know what utility for Windows has the same function as hexdump. I checked the program text, and here's the culprit: in `x – 1` there's a `U+2013 – EN DASH` being used as the minus sign (rather than the regular hypen-minus character), which is outside the ASCII range. Not sure how it got there, but I imagine the terrible programming language would also crash on this program. See XavierShay's answer below for how to get Ruby to work with it.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I would bet that `plainprogram.txt` was created using a word processor rather than a text editor.

Comment: And a final word of advice to nick n:  On Windows, install Cygwin to get zillions of programming tools, including `hexdump`.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 6):

Ruby typically defaults to UTF-8, but something about your environment/version does not appear to be. You can force an encoding like this:

```
File.readlines('plainprogram.txt', :encoding => 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: you know what you may be right, i am using an online compiler, and you code doesn't have slip throw and error

Answer (score 1):

You have a non-ascii character in the input, the following slight modification to your program can identify it in the absence of tools such as `hexdump`:

```
File.readlines("plainprogram.txt").each do |line|
  line.each_char { |chr| STDERR.puts "#{chr} : #{chr.ord}" if chr.ord > 127 }
  pieces = line.split()
end
```

Comment: thanks! helped me find an errant em-dash in a github branch name that was breaking our pre-commit hook

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to export these variables if you can:

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```